# How to use emoticons with Qt and C++

Tags: c++, qt, emoji

I have an application with a textedit field. I would like to use emoticons as well but unfortunetly I don't know much about it and couldn't find anything useful with Google either. I would like to have a selection box/list with emojis which I can chose from. A emoticon should be selected from there only not be transformed from an input like `:)` to an emoticon!

Are those just images that are selected and then inserted via HTML and I can just search and download such a image list somewhere?
Or are those special characters!?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Emojis aren't images these days, many of them are unicode characters. If the font you use to render the character supports that character you see it , else you don't ⌧. Read about emojis, atleast on Wikipedia, before trying to code with them.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification

Comment: I would recommend to use actual pictures. People sending you square boxes isn't fun.

Comment: if you are using QTextField, you can use textChanged() signal of QTextField, then you can have what user typed and according to input you can replace the characters with a emoticon image in text field :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254652/several-ways-of-placing-an-image-in-a-qtextedit

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a number of images of emoticons? Maybe http://getemoji.com/ can help? Or any search of "emoticons" in Google Image Search.

Hopefully this helps?

Comment: Ok, so this are just special characters I can simply insert as HTML and not images?

Comment: through http://getemoji.com/ you can get the special characters, yes. But maybe it is also possible to add images to your HTML? Just replace every string ":-)" with "<img src="path/to/smileyemoticon.png">" ? I have no clue, but could be possible